# Ansible sorting doesn't pick the highest number

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, artifacts

I'm trying to get few docker tags from Artifactory docker api and pick the latest tag in the list using Anisble sort but when I try sort its picking the single digit value over double digits ( example 9 over 15)

here are some example tags output list

the api output looks similar to this:
registered to `tag_output`

```
{
1.1.0-ab.7-9,
1.1.0-ab.8-10,
1.1.0-ab.9-12,
}
```

With the regex it picks up last char in the string after "-" which i'm trying to sort.
https://regex101.com/r/O7xH4u/1

using the same regex in the Ansible tasks when doing the sort, ansible is picking `1.1.0-ab.7-9` as it thinks 9 is greater then 12 (however, if we add '0' before 9 then it picks 12)

```
   - name: Get tags
      command: curl -u "{{artifactoryUser}}:{{artifactoryPwd}}" https://artifactory-mars.cd.genesaas.io/v2/xxxx/releases-candidates/1.1.0/from-service/tags/list
      register: tag_output

   - name: SetFact TAG
      set_fact:
        DCM_TAG: "{{ _dict|dict2items| sort(attribute='key')| map(attribute='value')|last }}"
      vars:
        _index: "{{ (tag_output.stdout | from_json).tags|map('regex_replace', '^(.*)-(.*)$', '\\2')|list }}"
        _dict: "{{ dict(_index|zip((tag_output.stdout | from_json).tags)) }}"
```

output:

```
TASK [SetFact TAG] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"DCM_TAG": "1.1.0-ab.7-9"}, "changed": false}
```

but I need expected output:

```
1.1.0-ab.9-12
```

Comment: In your question, your example value for `tag_output` isn't valid. What are the actual contents of `tag_output.stdout` when your playbook runs?

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of text. You can use regex101s "save regex" feature and share the link instead.

Comment: I updated my question for better understanding. tag_output is a register which contains a list of tags in json

Answer (score 2):

Put the tags into a list

```yaml
tags_list: "{{ tag_output.keys()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
tags_list:
  - 1.1.0-ab.7-9
  - 1.1.0-ab.8-10
  - 1.1.0-ab.9-12
```

Parse the attributes

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tags: "{{ tags|d([]) + [{'tag': item,
                                 'major': major|int,
                                 'minor': minor|int}] }}"
      loop: "{{ tags_list }}"
      vars:
        ext: "{{ item|split('.')|last }}"
        major: "{{ ext|split('-')|first }}"
        minor: "{{ ext|split('-')|last }}"
```

gives

```yaml
tags:
  - major: 7
    minor: 9
    tag: 1.1.0-ab.7-9
  - major: 8
    minor: 10
    tag: 1.1.0-ab.8-10
  - major: 9
    minor: 12
    tag: 1.1.0-ab.9-12
```

Now, find the largest major and minor, and select the tag

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          Latest version: {{ tags_max.major }}-{{ tags_max.minor }}
          DCM_TAG: {{ DCM_TAG }}
      vars:
        major_max: "{{ tags|map(attribute='major')|max }}"
        tags_major_max: "{{ tags|selectattr('major', 'eq', major_max|int) }}"
        minor_max: "{{ tags_major_max|map(attribute='minor')|max }}"
        tags_max: "{{ tags_major_max|selectattr('minor', 'eq', minor_max|int)|first }}"
        DCM_TAG: "{{ tags_max.tag }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    Latest version: 9-12
    DCM_TAG: 1.1.0-ab.9-12
```

---

**Note**

Testing multiple minors, e.g.

```yaml
tag_output:
  {
    1.1.0-ab.7-9,
    1.1.0-ab.8-10,
    1.1.0-ab.9-10,
    1.1.0-ab.9-12,
    1.1.0-ab.9-7,
  }
```

gives the correct result too

```yaml
    Latest version: 9-12
    DCM_TAG: 1.1.0-ab.9-12
```